# How do I load a particular line in a TMUX session?

Tags: tmux

The scrolling is soo slow in TMUX 2.7+. I have a TMUX session with a window that has 5,000 lines of code and I'd like to access a command that I sent around line 2,000. It would take forever to load it up.

I've tried going into command mode and putting in the number.

How do I access a specific line in a tmux session?

Comment: Why not use your shell's history feature to retrieve the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `goto-line` command lets you jump directly to given line. If you use `vi` mode, it's `:2000`. If you use `emacs` mode, it's `g2000`.